# Request specific fields (not all fields) with RediSearch

Tags: performance, search, redis, redisearch

[Here's an official example of a RediSearch query](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Quick_Start/):

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myIdx "hello world" LIMIT 0 10
1) (integer) 1
2) "doc1"
3) 1) "title"
   2) "hello world"
   3) "body"
   4) "lorem ipsum"
   5) "url"
   6) "http://redis.io"
```

My question is, how could I request just one or two fields, e.g. just to get back to the "title" value ("hello world") or the "ID" and "title" fields ([1, "hello world"]). Mainly for performance reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it supports it with the `RETURN` option.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH myIdx "hello world" LIMIT 0 10 RETURN 2 title url
```

See: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsearch

Comment: Exactly! :) Also, there's a way to do it with aggregations.

Comment: @ItamarHaber who knew!

Comment: just to point out, if `title` and `url` are not indexed, you need to use a JSON path. otherwise it returns `null`